# Vue.js - Is It bad practice to use a local method within computed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am using Vuex state as a trigger of an event (eventBus).

I trigger the event with:

```
this.$store.dispatch('triggerRefetch');
```

and process it with:

```
computed: {
    trigger: function(){ 
        return this.$store.getters['triggerFlag'] 
    }
},
watch: function(newV, oldV){
    this.handleTrigger();
},
```

Here I don't need the new value nor the old value. So instead, is it okay to just use computed for this like:

```
computed: {
    trigger: function(){ 
        this.handleTrigger();
        return this.$store.getters['triggerFlag'] 
    }
},
```

Would it be a bad way to use computed this way for Vuex (event bus)? In addition is there even a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that's a bad practice to run some extra logic inside the computed property, a property is a just a property that returns some data it's not a function or a method that run a bunch of logic, keep the first approach which is best in terms of readability and extensibility, that allow your code to follow some clear flow.

```
computed: {
    trigger: function(){ 
        return this.$store.getters['triggerFlag'] 
    }
},
watch: {
 trigger: function(){
    this.handleTrigger();
},
```